# Update two columns in pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this function (Update) to update data in mysql table with pdo 
when using this function to update one  column it's working fine.
but when using it to update multiple  columns , this function will add last value to all columns 
you can look to problem in photo 
http://postimg.org/image/z1kv5jh9j/
blew the code I use 
help plz

```
<?php
public function query($sql, $fields = array()){

        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
            $i = 1;
            if($i <= count($fields)){
                foreach ($fields as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindParam($i, $param);
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            //die($sql);
            if($this->_query->execute()){
                return $this->_query;
            }

        }

    }

    public function Update($tbl_name, $fields = array(),$id){
        $set = '';
        $x = 1;
        $bindvalues = array_values($fields);
        foreach ($fields as $columns => $values) {
            $set .= "`{$columns}` =?";
            if ($x < count($fields)){
                $set .= ", ";
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $id = intval($id);
        $sql = "UPDATE `{$tbl_name}` SET {$set} WHERE `id`={$id} ";
        //die($sql);
        if($this->query($sql,$fields) == true){
            echo "Data updated Successfully";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Did you use the ":" for the parameters in the query? Normaly the Query looks like "Update table SET VALUES param=:param ..." Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @ms88-aut He is using unnamed params. `$set .= "\`{$columns}\` =?"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()` because `bindParam()` is passed to PDO byref. This makes it always use the last value set in `$param` variable.

```
public function query($sql, $fields = array()){

        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
            $i = 1;
            if($i <= count($fields)){
                foreach ($fields as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($i, $param);
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            //die($sql);
            if($this->_query->execute()){
                return $this->_query;
            }

        }

    }
```